# Game data - arrays of instances or arrays of values?

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

I'm making a game and need to store a fair bit of animation data. For each frame I have about 15 values to store. My initial idea was to have a list of "frame" objects that contain those values. Then I thought I could also just have separate lists for each of the values and skip the objects altogether. The data will be loaded once from an XML file when the game is started.
I'm just looking for advice here, is either approach at all better (speed, memory usage, ease of use, etc) than the other?
Sorry if this is a dumb question, still pretty new and couldn't find any info on stuff like this.
(PS: this is a 2D game with sprites, so 1 frame != 1 frame of screen time. I estimate somewhere around 500-1000 frames total)

Comment: what does that data describe ?

Comment: Most likely, storing instances of `Frame` objects will be better, because it will make the data structure clearer and easier for you to work with.

Comment: Why would you want to store them in lists?

Comment: A good point actually T. Kiley. I am making an editor for the animations as well, so they will need to be lists for that, but for the finalized animations they can be loaded into arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the animation data is not changing, you could use a struct instead of an class, which combines the "namespacing" of objects with the "value-typeness" of primitives. That will make all the values of a single frame reside in the same space, and save you some memory and page faults.

Just make sure that the size of your arrays doesn't get you into LOH if you intend to allocate and deallocate them often.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll give that a go. The data will never change once loaded, so that's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating an animation So you  should  keep in mind a few basic things of.net:

- Struct is created on stack. So, it is faster to instantiate (and destroy) a struct than a class.
- On the other hand, every time you assign a structure or pass it to a function, it gets copied.
- you can still pass struct by reference simply by specifying ref in the function parameter list

So it will  be better to keep in mind this things